# Add settings to WatchFace in Android Wear app

Tags: android, wear-os

I noticed that some WatchFaces have an option "Get Companion App", clicking on this setting Android Wear leads user to Google Play page of the relevant application.

How is it possible to implement so?

Answer (score 0):

This question is really too broad to provide a complete answer here. But at a high level, here's how you'd implement it:

1. Create a separate app on the handheld, probably built around a `PreferenceScreen`. This is your companion app.
2. Use the Wear Data API to send those `Preference` values to your watch face.
3. On the watch side, listen for changes to your preference data and modify your face accordingly.
4. Package the watch face app within the handheld companion app for distribution on Google Play (or wherever).

Obviously, there are a **lot** of details to each step - but they're all well documented elsewhere. I'd also suggest that you look at (or build from) Google's example watch face app, https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace, which includes a handheld configuration app.

Comment: That's correct, I have all this infrastructure. The question is that when I click on my WatchFace in Android Wear I don't have an option to install a relevant Companion app from Google Play

Comment: Perhaps you need to elaborate your question, then - you made no mention that you had already written the companion app. Exactly what aspect of providing this option to the user is giving you trouble? [Also, why not have the "companion app" be the handheld app in which your watch face is packaged for Google Play?]